# How does send and receive work in Ethernet over power and what standard describes this?

Tags: ac, filter, communication, ethernet, power-line-communication

From what I understand in 100/1000BASE-TX Ethernet, two pairs are adopted; one for transmitting and the other for receiving. What I'm wondering is how Ethernet over power works given that it's essentially a single pair?

I understand the fundamental principle of Ethernet over power, i.e. the much higher frequency is injected into the low frequency AC, and then we can use a filter to extract that information, but I don't understand how both sending and receiving can happen at the same time?

Comment: Google powerline communication

Comment: Let’s not confuse PoE (power over Ethernet) and powerline communication whereby signals are sent over the mains wiring.

Comment: they are different physical layers.  and note that 10/100 and gigabit do not work the same way over cat6/twisted pairs.  nor does the newer 2.5 nor 5 over the same wires.   different solutions over the same media as well as different solutions over different media.

Comment: you can make a tx/rx loopback for 10/100 but not gigabit for example (not full duplex). (to the same port).

Comment: _"in 100/1000BASE-TX Ethernet, two pairs are adopted; one for transmitting and the other for receiving"_ - That's how it works for 100BASE-TX. In 1000BASE-T (-TX is not used in practice), all 4 pairs are used simultaneously in both directions.

Comment: @Transistor & Kartman - You're both right.  I misread the title.  I'll just delete those two comments as they really aren't relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like radio and TV where you have multiple channels (i.e. different frequencies) you can have multiple carriers imposed upon the mains. At its simplest, one carrier frequency is used for transmit and another used for receive.

A similar technique is used for WDM (wavelength division multiplexing) over optic fibers - different color (wavelength) lasers are used for the send and receive channels and optic filters are used to separate the two channels. Thus you only need one fiber.

Actual implementations of powerline communication are far more complex to maximise the data rate over a very imperfect media (the mains) and to mitigate the effects of interference. Similar techniques are used for ADSL and VDSL over telephone lines.